# C++ (press button 1, show bitmap "P", 2sec, hide bitmap "P")

Tags: c++, bitmap, show-hide

I am using C++ , and I want to do this in a dialog box.

Press button 1, show bitmap "P", wait 2sec, hide bitmap "P", press button 1 again.....

```
void CPreparationDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    GetDlgItem(IDC_P)->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    SetTimer(0, 2000, NULL);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_P)->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
}
```

In this dialogbox I have do 4 buttons and 4 different pictures respectively.
The buttons are 1,2,3,4, pictures are IDC_P, IDC_L, IDC_E, IDC_K.

!!!!!
After I tried these code for button 1, the bitmap cannot be shown. I am only able to do is show, but it can't hide.

```
void CPreparationDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    GetDlgItem(IDC_P)->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
} 

void CPreparationDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    GetDlgItem(IDC_L)->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}


void CPreparationDlg::OnBnClickedButton3()
{
    GetDlgItem(IDC_E)->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}


void CPreparationDlg::OnBnClickedButton4()
{    
GetDlgItem(IDC_K)->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

I have also tried these, but it underline the "IDC_P" in CALLBACK, and said it **argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type HWND**

```
void CPreparationDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    GetDlgItem(IDC_P)->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    UINT TimerId = SetTimer(0, 2000, &TimerProc);
}
VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT nIDEvent, DWORD dwTime) 
{

    GetDlgItem(**IDC_P**)->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
void CPreparationDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    GetDlgItem(IDC_P)->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    Sleep(2000);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_P)->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
}
```

But this would halt your app until the 2 seconds are up.

You could also try using `AfxBeginThread`, or `CreateThread` to create a thread to do
this for you, so it doesn't halt your application.

But I think the most viable option would be to use a Windows timer as you have in your example, and handle `WM_TIMER` messages in the window procedure, not exactly well versed in how you'd go about that in MFC, but I hope this post was at least of some help to you.

Comment: Thank you David Otano, I have tried Sleep(2000) before, but it cant shown the picture at all.

Comment: see question/n

I have also tried these, but it underline the "IDC_P" in CALLBACK, and said it <<argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type HWND>>


    void CPreparationDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
    {
     GetDlgItem(IDC_P)->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
      UINT TimerId = SetTimer(0, 2000, &TimerProc);
    }
    VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT nIDEvent, DWORD dwTime) 
    {
 
     GetDlgItem(IDC_P)->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    }